# MS Access 2010: VBA code runs multiple times

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have a problem which I never had before and I cannot see any mistakes.

On a form is a button *cmdCreateOrder* which runs a pass-through query to a SQL Server and executes a stored procedure and this query returns a value to Access.

The button *cmdCreateOrder*:

```vb
Private Sub cmdCreateOrder_Click()
Dim strsql As String
Dim intNumberProducts As Integer

If MsgBox("Want to create an order?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
        & "Click 'Yes' to create", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Question") = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
End If

    strsql = "exec dbo.spCreateOrder 'CreateOrdersKd', 1, " & Me.OfferID & ", " & Me.KdID & ", " & TempVars!intUser
    Debug.Print strsql
    Call SQL_PT(strsql, "PT_LookupWerte")

    intNumberProducts = DLookup("NumberProducts", "PT_LookupWerte")

    Me.Bestelldatum = Date
end Sub
```

The function *SQL_PT*:

```vb
Function SQL_PT(ByVal SQL As String, Optional QueryName As String)  
Dim qdf As QueryDef

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'if no query name then create temp qry
If Len(QueryName) = 0 Then 'temp Abfrage

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    With qdf
        .Connect = TempVars!ConnectionString
        .SQL = SQL
        .ReturnsRecords = False  'Wenn kein QueryName angeliefert wird, dann ergibt .ReturnsRecords = 0 und die Abfrage wird einfach ausgeführt
        .Execute
    End With

Else  'if a qry name provided, then run qry which returns values
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName)
    qdf.SQL = SQL
End If

qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing

ExitHere:
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

I use many codes like this in this project and all of them work correctly. But this button click runs the `EXEC` at least 3 times and creates 3 (or more) orders.

**Access VBA Debug Test**

Even more strange, as I only get ONE line in the Immediate Window.
When I use the `Debug.Print` result (e.g. `exec dbo.spCreateOrder 'CreateOrdersKd', 1, 8, 2001, 1`)  in a PT query (`PT_LookupWerte`), it is working correctly as expected with just **ONE** order.

**SQL Server Stored Proc Test**

When I run the stored procedure on the SQL Server: `exec dbo.spCreateOrder 'CreateOrdersKd', 1, 8, 2001, 1` it also creates just one order and it runs correctly.

Only when clicking the button in Access it runs multiple times.

I compact and repaired and de-compiled the database. Now I do not know any further what the problem is.

Any ideas?

Comment: what code's behind `SQL_PT`?   Also possibly unrelated but shouldn't `DLookup("NumberProducts", "PT_LookupWerte")` have some criteria as a 3rd parameter?

Comment: I added the function SQL_PT in my question.

Comment: *creates 3 (or more) orders* ... where are orders being created here? How do you know it runs three times?

Comment: @Parfait: because I get 3 new orders by the stored procedure exec dbo.spCreateOrder 'CreateOrdersKd'... If I run the same sp on the server or execute the PT query with that SQL statement in access, the result is correct!!! That is why I cannot find an explanation for it. It is also correct when I do not add the name of any PT_query (such as "PT_LookupWerte") in the function, which should retrieve values from the sp. As I said, I never before in many databases I had this experience. With fnc SQL_PT I retrieve also data for reports from any sp and it is correct. So what can be wrong??

Comment: Forgive me but you did not exactly answer my question. What is the specific output that tells you 3 orders were created? And for example not 1 or even 100 orders? In fact, what is *orders*? An Access report? All your code shows is a `DLookUp` call? Does something else happen when button is clicked?

Comment: Parfait, the stored procedure adds records directly on the server. The pt query returns only the number of article ordered in the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DAO to execute stored procedures (like your `SQL_PT` does) is a bad plan.

Storing stored procedures in QueryDefs and executing them using `DLookUp` instead of `.Execute` or `.OpenRecordset` is a terrible plan.

A simple fix would be to replace `intNumberProducts = DLookup("NumberProducts", "PT_LookupWerte")` with `intNumberProducts = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("PT_LookupWerte").OpenRecordset.Fields("NumberProducts").Value`

A better fix is to move your stored procedure code to ADO, and use command objects and parameters to execute stored procedures.

Comment: Erik, for example I check the login  data of this application the same way and it works. I use this way of retrieving data for years and in many databases. I will delete all the querydefs and create them for new, maybe for any reason they are corrupt.

Comment: Nope, the technique using `DLookUp` is just flawed. For retrieving data, it's just inefficient, but for updating data, it can cause errors. You should adjust it.

Comment: Ok, I try a recordsource solution instead to find out if the problem vanishes. Thx

Comment: Correction: recordset, not recordsource!

Comment: Erik, thanks a lot, it works with your solution! I did not know, that Dlookup (or most probably all domain functions ??) have such influence on server functions!

Comment: If the solution worked, please mark the answer as accepted, so others can see the question is answered.

Comment: See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369403). It's the check mark on the left of the answer.